# How can you pipe the output of a script that has ${1+"$@"} variables used within it?

Tags: bash, variables, parameters, grep, pipe

There are a bunch of scripts that I would like to run and grep the output.  For example, running this works and has the desired output lines:

```
$ myScript.sh
```

Running this does not:

```
$ myScript.sh | grep something
```

After further review, myScript.sh has this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh     
...
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  the.real.script.is.here ${1+"$@"}
```

I am assuming that the " | grep something" gets sucked into the $@ list. Any ideas on how I can pipe the output easily? Thanks!

**EDIT:**  Thanks everyone for the info about how variables are parsed.  It must be something else that is the problem. Maybe it is what I am grepping for.  In my output I am looking for lines with "/SE_2012.old".  I ran the script again with "|grep old" and got **no** output.  I ran it with  "| grep SE", and got a result.  I ran it again with "old" to see if I was going crazy, and it **DID** give me a result.

Comment: I don't think that you've given enough information here to tell what's going on. It's certainly not possible that the pipe is being consumed by the argument handling in the script.

Comment: Unfortunately the only things I left out was a check if JAVA_HOME was set, and a classpath location.  I will investigate further though.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your assumption is incorrect. The shell parses its command line well enough to tell the difference between a pipe and an argument. That's why you need quotes in order to escape redirects, pipes, subshells, and other low-level expressions.

Now, to the problem at hand: Assuming you don't see *any* output when you run

```
$ myScript.sh | grep something
```

you're probably seeing the [effect of buffering](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)*. Unfortunately, I can't tell you exactly how it's happening in the java application, so I can't give you a direct solution to it, but perhaps if you examine the internals of the java code you can tell.

* As opposed to the output just going someplace other than standard output.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for "| grep something" to be sucked into the $@ list, so there should be another problem. Maybe the script uses line buffering for tty output, and full buffering otherwise? (Do you wait for script completion before concluding it doesn't work?) Maybe "something" in "grep something" gets interpreted (unexpectedly) as regular expression that doesn't match input lines?

- Try `cat` instead of `grep something`: does it work?
- Show us the real value of "something".